# Facing problem in writing and reading on file using Formatter in java

Tags: java

Here, I can write on the file. But when I'm trying to read my file it's giving me "MyFile.txt" but my output should be " I'm 20"
What is wrong in my code?

```
import java.util.*;
class main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Formatter fr;

        try{
            fr = new Formatter("MyFile.txt");

            fr.format("I'm %d",20);

            fr.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner("MyFile.txt");
            while (sc.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(sc.next());
            }
             sc.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A few suggestions... ;-) 1. Follow [standard naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and capitalize your class name – so `Main` instead of `main`. 2. Give your class a name that reflects what it's doing, even `Practice` would be better than "main". 3. Instead of `System.out.println("Error")`, try something like `e.printStackTrace()` so that you see more than the word "Error" when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing a string literal to the Scanner constructor.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("MyFile.txt");
```

That's [the constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)) that scans the string itself.

You want to pass it a File object instead:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("MyFile.txt"));
```

**Note:** Writing to a file with a Formatter the way you do works because the [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.lang.String)) constructor that takes a String assumes that the string is a file name. The Scanner constructor assumes that the string itself is the input, not a file name.